# Time Capsule still provides Wi-Fi but is not discovered by AirPort Utility

Tags: wifi, time-machine, airport, time-capsule

I connect to the Internet with my Time Capsule's Wi-Fi, and it works perfectly. I also have been backing up to the same Time Capsule with Time Machine. But now, after about 18 months, Time Machine complains that it can not find the backup drive. I checked AirPort Utility, and there I just see the "Internet" sphere and the green dot letting me know I'm connected successfully. The Time Capsule neither shows up nor can it be discovered.

I rebooted the Time Capsule several times. LED is first yellow and then green, like I'd expect as normal.

**What could be wrong? How can I troubleshoot?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps and it should be OK:

1. Press the reset button on the Time Capsule.
2. Forget the old time capsule in Airport Utility.
3. Re-add the reset Time Capsule.
4. Update the Time Capsule's firmware.

The Back to My Mac function caused it to be not seen by the Airport Utility despite it working fine otherwise.